# Eclipse Oxygen JSP validation errors specific with nested JSTL tags

Tags: eclipse, jsp

```
<option value="something" <c:if test="${ }">selected</c:if>>something</option>
```

This line of code gets highlighted in Eclipse Oxygen, however, I was previously using Neon and this line was totally fine. Running the application is fine and there's no errors rendering the page whatsoever.

I wonder if this is specific with Oxygen or is there some settings that I'm missing here.

**Edit:**
The line gets highlighted for missing end tag for `c:if`, and for `<option>` not closed properly, expected `'>'`

Comment: I noticed the same problem. I think it's a bug in the jsp validator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved the same problem in this way:
 [bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518987](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518987)

- Download the Feature patch against WTP 3.9.0
- UnZIP file and rename 518987-patch01\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.html.core_1.2.101.v20170704_fix518987_01.jar to org.eclipse.wst.html.core_1.2.100.v201705012043.jar
- use 518987-patch01\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.html.core_1.2.100.v201705012043.jar to replace your-eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.html.core_1.2.100.v201705012043.jar

Comment: For Oxygen this did not work. When you do a replace the original missing breaks the IDE, if you have them side by side you still have the original issue. My guess is that we will have to install the patch. Looking to figure that process out at this time.

Comment: If you could explain how you were able to apply the patch. It is not as simple as replace in the filesystem. I know you can change the feature itself but all the examples I have seen do not give a good detailed step by step. Did you rename the jar?

Comment: sorry,I wrote one step less，i changed it in the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.  with Eclipse Oxygen, just go to menu, Help -> Check for Updates

Select all, wait, restart when prompted and JSTL will format just fine with